# How should I handle user-facing plugins in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, electron

I would like to add a plugin system to my Electron application so that my users can add new features to my application. I was originally thinking that I would let my users upload a `.zip` containing a plugin and then it would extract, and require the plugin to use it within the application. I then ran into problems with the idea.

1. How should I handle a plugin which has dependencies since I cannot use `npm` (e.g `lodash`)?
2. How can I give the plugin an API to use (e.g getting application theme or resource name)

I am not sure how this could be handled, I've looked around for similar cases but haven't found them. My ultimate goal is to have a system that works in Electron similar to how Wordpress plugins work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow, and would depend entirely on the project and the desired end result. If it were me, as a general purpose type solution, I would probably integrate an existing [userscript manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript_manager) if possible, or [implement one](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block).

Comment: Why is it that you can not use `npm`? See an example of an electron app using npm: https://github.com/gurayyarar/NodeJsPackageManager/blob/master/js/services/NpmService.js#L69

Comment: @Gatsbimantico Because the user may not have it installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `npm` as a child process.

You can implement your own:

```
require('child_process').exec(
  'npm ...',
  { maxBuffer: 1024 * 500 },
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    var response = JSON.parse(stdout).dependencies;
    ...
  }
);
```

or use a library, as an example: https://github.com/getstation/electron-package-manager

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much!